# python не считает количество проходов через цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Всем привет.
Написал скрипт для публикации записи на стенах групп ВК.
Суть проблемы:
Цикл `while`, в нем цикл `for` в котором перебирается список групп из txt файла и подставляется видео из списка по индексу. Индекс увеличивается после полного прохода цикла `for`.
Проблема:
После прохода цикла `for` не увеличивается счетчик.
Скрипт работает у меня на винде, версия питона 3.8.0. Все работает нормально. Только что прогонял дебагом, все ок. Проблема у меня возникает, если скрипт работает на сервере ubuntu, с версией питона 3.8.2. Но я не думаю, что есть какая то разница в версиях питона, что могло повлиять на это
Опыта в программировании у меня мало.. Не пинайте) Спасибо.

```
    from datetime import datetime
    from time import sleep
    import requests
    
    # ПОЛУЧЕНИЕ ТОКЕНА
    username = input('Login: ')
    password = input('Password: ')
    
    resp = requests.post(
        f'https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=3697615&client_secret=AlVXZFMUqyrnABp8ncuU&username={username}&password={password}').json()
    token = resp["access_token"]
    
    # ПОЛУЧЕНИЕ СПИСКА ГРУПП
    with open('group.txt', 'r') as g_file:
        group = g_file.read().splitlines()
    
    # ПОЛУЧЕНИЕ СПИСКА ВИДЕО
    with open('video.txt', 'r') as v_file:
        video = v_file.read().splitlines()
    
    
    def spam(group, video, token):
        count = 0
        kol = 0
        while True:
            try:
                for g in group:
                    resp = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post'
                                        f'?owner_id={g}'  # ID group
                                        f'&attachments={video[count]}'  # video
                                        '&from_group=0'
                                        f'&access_token={token}&v=5.122')  # token
                    res = resp.json().get('response').get('post_id')
                    if res == int(res):
                        print(resp.json())
                        print(datetime.today().strftime(f'%H:%M:%S | Пост отправлен!\n'
                                                        f'Группа: {g}\n'
                                                        f'Видео: {video[count]}'))
                        print(datetime.today().strftime(f'%H:%M:%S | Отправлено постов: {kol+1}\n'
                                                        f'Пауза 1 час.'))
                        kol += 1
                        sleep(3600)
    
                count += 1 # ЭТА ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ НЕ УВЕЛИЧИВАЕТ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ
                if count > len(video)-1:  # если количество отправленных видео больше списка видео
                    count = 0
            except AttributeError:
                try:
                    if resp.json().get('error').get('error_code') == 214:   # если ошибка 214 - пропускаем
                        print(datetime.today().strftime(f'%H:%M:%S | Ошибка при отправке поста. Возможно ЧС.'))
                except:
                    print(datetime.today().strftime(f'%H:%M:%S | Произошла ошибка.'))
                    print(resp.json())
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        spam(group, video, token)
```

Comment: Могу предположить, что то что описано в try не выполняется из за каких то ошибок. Поэтому  count не считает.

Comment: @RomanR , Если в блоке try выходит ошибка, то мы попадает в блок except, в котором уже сообщается о возникшей ошибке. Это видно в консоли. Скрин https://imgur.com/a/rxQgbkm

Comment: В коде count есть только в этом куске count += 1  # ЭТА ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ НЕ УВЕЛИЧИВАЕТ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ
            print(count)
            if count > len(video) - 1:  # если количество отправленных видео больше списка видео
                count = 0 Значит либо этот кусок не обрабатывается, либо он обнуляется условием. Поставь print(count) после count += 1 и после условия тогда будет видно как он меняется. Или посмотри что там происходит в дебаггере

Comment: @RomanR , У меня еще кое что... Скрипт работает у меня на винде, версия питона 3.8.0. Все работает нормально. Только что прогонял дебагом, все ок. Проблема у меня возникает, если скрипт работает на сервере ubuntu, с версией питона 3.8.2. Но я не думаю, что есть какая то разница в версиях питона, что могло повлиять на это....

Comment: На ubuntu же скрипт почему то не доходит до строки увеличения count += 1..

Comment: слип ведь в секундах . 3600 секунд==60 минут

Comment: @Интик , ну да, а что не так?)

Comment: ну попадая в ту ветку будет ждать час и не дойдёт до каунтера

Comment: @Интик, по написанной логике, ждем 1 час после увеличиваем count, проверяем условие и повторно заходим в блок try только с увеличенным count.

Comment: уточню. вы ждали час или уменьшали время, чтобы проверить что каунт не увеличется ?

Comment: @Интик скрипт у меня работал сутки, и за сутки count не увеличился. Я проверял работу на своем ПК без отправки запроса requests, а просто выводя принты. Все работает нормально. Я уже грешу все таки на разницу в версиях питона...

Comment: В общем установил на своей сервер GUI, с интерфейсом потестил, вроде теперь считает. Точный результат будет известен через 22 часа. Версия питона осталась та же, с чем связно хз. Посмотрим что получится дальше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем. Разобрался. Оказывается, попадались группы в которых аккаунт был в ЧС, соответственно после строки `res = resp.json().get('response').get('post_id')` мы попадали в блок `except` и по новой заходили в цикл - и так на репите, то есть из цикла `for` мы без ошибок не выходили и не увеличивали счетчик.
Переписал код, теперь все работает.
Всем спасибо)